# Inexplicable advertisements in progressive web app

Tags: ads, progressive-web-apps, google-tag-manager, cloudflare

For a PWA that we created, we got some users telling there is advertisements in the bottom of the screen. Before telling them that their phone has some kind of malware, I want to be sure that the advertisement is not caused from our end.

The only two 'external' resources we have are Font-Awesome (css) via cloudfare.com and Google Analytics (JS) via googletagmanager.com.

I can't imagine, but is one of these two known for adding (unwanted) ads to pages?

[See bottom of the page in this screenshot; there is an inexplicable advertisement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbGRT.jpg)

Update: it was caused by the app 'QR Reader' on iPhone.

Comment: Any links in your PWA to an external website? That looks like a browser. If you can, share the link to you PWA so others can check.